# Remove Black Background When Hovering

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image]

I'm on my early stages of creating a Rails application. What I wanted to do is remove the black background on the links when hovering the cursor on them (as shown in the image). How? I did not add anything on the css files. I'm using Rails 3.2

Comment: I did not do anything on the css file. This seems to be the default 'css theme' or rails 3.2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems to be that the culprit to this is at `assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss`

```css
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one i can say:

```
a:hover {
background-color:transparent;
}
```